# How to safely remove pump chuck from Schrader valve

Tags: pump, valves, schrader

I just pumped up my tire, and then ripped off the valve when trying to take the chuck off, and consequently the air.

I've learned that I shouldn't twist when trying to remove the chuck, but what else can I do to make it easier?

Thanks

Comment: There are about a dozen different styles of chucks, and it's impossible to offer specific advice without knowing the style.  Probably the best advice would be to take the pump to a bike shop and ask them to show you how to use it.  (You can buy a replacement tube at the same time.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ripping off the valve is a pretty rare occurence I think. If you manage to pull the valve off or even just spring a leak while removing the chuck then the inside of the rim (where the root of valve connects to the innertube and hits the inside of the rim) could be too sharp or the protective rim tape could be damaged or mis-aligned. This is the first thing I'd check.

Beyond that I think the [top voted answer](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/a/3786/424) here to [this almost identical question for presta valves](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/3765/how-to-safely-remove-pump-off-presta-valve?rq=1) is good concrete advice.
I would suggest you:

- Make sure you unlocked the chuck properly.
- Just pull straight away from de valve to get the chuck off (no twisting or bending or wiggling)
- Be mindfull of the amount of force you use (both to avoid pulling the valve off, and to avoid slamming your hand into the spokes or something else as the chuck comes loose.